# How do you handle events on controls created during the GridView.RowDataBound event?

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, datagridview

So on the .NET `GridView` control there's a `RowDataBound` event, at which time I create a `DropDownList` for each row in a particular column.

When that `DropDownList` changes on the client, I can get it to post back, but the control's state is already gone. What's the best approach to handling events for controls created during the `RowDataBound` event?

Comment: Can you post some code, I am kind of confused on how you are creating these drop down lists.  Also, just curious, why not create the drop down list in your GridView?  You could pretty much avoid this problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious: why are you adding these `DropDownList`s to the `GridView` in the `RowDataBound` event? I genuinely can't think of a reason to do this.

Even if you have just a placeholder `DropDownList` in the original `RowTemplate`, you should be able to bind the control and assign appropriate event handlers.

Comment: Because it should only be shown in certain circumstances, where as all other times it should just be the default cell display (text). Is there a cleaner way to do this through the row template?

Comment: Yeah, set their `Visible` properties to `false`. Then, you can show the appropriate ones in your `RowDataBound` event. There are good examples on SO that will show you how to find controls in a `RowDataBound` event if you aren't familiar.